# I want to modify the focus of EDITTEXT , performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS) always return false on editText

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I want to clear the input focus from an `editText` in my accessibility service on a specific action.

I get the node with the input focus and try to clear it but performAction always return false:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
AccessibilityNodeInfo focus = root.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);

if(focus != null){

    focus.getText(); //return the text in my input
    focus.isFocusable(); //return true
    focus.isFocused(); // return true
    focus.getActions(); //Return the bitmask that contain the Action_clear_focus

    boolean sucess = focus.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS);
    Log.v(TAG, "sucess = " + sucess); //Always return FALSE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of specific handling for ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS for EditText. The return value for the action in View.java is just !isFocused().

If you own the app code as well, you might just step through the code there and see what's going on. If the app decides that focus needs to be somewhere, and places it back on the EditText, for example, you could get your observed behavior.